# What does tx.wait(1) do?

Tags: blockchain, transactions, ethereumjs

Can Someone please explain what does tx.wait(1) do? And also what does it mean by block confirmations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tx.wait(1)` means that it will wait until your transaction is confirmed in 1 block;

Block confirmations is the amount of blocks that have been added to the blockchain after your transaction was included in a block(mined)

My response comes from [here](https://jaredstauffer.medium.com/what-is-a-block-confirmation-on-ethereum-e27d29ca8c01)

Comment: So, basically when I initiate a trasaction, my transaction gets included in a block and then it waits for those no.(here, 1) of blocks to get added to the blockchain and only after that my block gets added to the blockchain.. right? or am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, when you initiate a transaction it gets to a "miners pool", it is a storage of all pending transactions and its usually handled by your RPC provider ie. Alchemy;

Once your TX is in the pool its basically waiting for miners to include it in a block.

so the tx.wait(1) is making the execution of your code to wait until the TX is been taken from the pool by miners and included in a block.

if you store the return of tx.wait(1) you will be getting a transaction receipt

const receipt = await tx.wait(1)